# 2 bootstrap modals with max-width and max-height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create 2 modals in bootstrap themed webpage.

[image]

I am done with the creation of the wider modal.

Here is the code,

```
.modal-dialog {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    max-width:900px;
}
```

The output of the wider modal with this code is what I expected.

But the problem now is the smaller modal.

The smaller modal should be responsive. 
It should have max-width of 360px and max-height of 340px.

Should I change the .modal-dialog css for the smaller modal?

Comment: Can you share somewhere your whole code you have written till now?

Comment: the css in my question is the only one related to modal sizing.

Comment: I tried changing top:10px to auto. and bottom:10px to auto. and then added max-height:340px. But it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to create a new variant of the default modal to cater for different sizes and behaviours:

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myWiderModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-wider">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body> ... </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallerModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-smaller">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body> ... </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.modal-dialog {
  &.modal-wider {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    max-width: 900px;
  }

  &.modal-smaller {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    max-width:360px;

    .modal-body {
        max-height: 340px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I used your code but the problem is that, the smaller modal is not in the center and have more than 340px height.

Comment: If you need to vertically center a box you have to resort to the famous two-liner: top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%);. In regard to the height, you can adjust that on modal-body. If you set the height on the dialog itself you will end up with cropped content.

Answer (score -2):

You can try something like this (without bootstrap) :

#### HTML :

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog-small">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS :

```
.modal-dialog {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    max-width:900px;
    background: red;
}

.modal-dialog-small {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    background: blue;
    max-width: 360px;
    max-height: 340px;
    margin-top: 50vh;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

[Fiddle JS link](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ysxt11rj/)

Danny H answer is more complete than mine.

Comment: kindly write the code here instead of giving a link